# What's __halt_compiler in PHP for?

Tags: php

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.halt-compiler.php):

```
void __halt_compiler ( void )
```

> This function halts the execution of the compiler. This can be useful to embed data in PHP scripts, like the installation files.
>
> Note: `__halt_compiler()` can only be used from the outermost scope.

Can anyone provide an actually case where this function is useful?

Comment: Pretty sure it's meant to be a debugging tool more than anything else. I don't believe the "embed data" thing.

Comment: @Bolt - you sure?  im thinking of it as like an `END` statement, but there could be stuff after it thats accessed either through reflection or as plaintext

Comment: In support of @BoltClock's comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.halt-compiler.php#98655

Comment: @jon_darkstar: If I understand the way reflection works, it won't be able to reach that portion since it's not seen by the interpreter. Plaintext would be what the manual seems to be implying the data can be used for, but I question the necessity of having such data there in the first place...

Comment: mainly compiling purpose, like building a RPM using PHP, you can use this function to stop PHP from execution

Comment: But why not stop PHP by `exit` ?

Comment: @compiler: Because PHP would already be running by the time `exit` is called; `__halt_compiler` tells PHP to ignore everything after it as if it were inside one big `/* comment */`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Assume you have one script with some php code and lots and lots of binary clutter.

```
<?php doStuff(); __halt_compliler(); [BIG_BINARY_MESS]
```

then you want the compiler to NOT try to parse the binary because if there is `<?` somewhere in the binary it would break.

The point is being able to just ship *one* file with binary data and php code.

For a little example see [this blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20101012214224/http://mgccl.com/2007/01/04/halt-compiler-make-install-files-for-php-smaller)

---

So you want not only to stop the `execution` of a script (like `exit()` would) but to stop the `parsing` so that you can have "invalid syntax" at the end of file and php still can execute the first part.

---

### Another example:

This will get parsed as valid php and execute just fine:

```
<?php $a = 1; echo $a; __halt_compiler(); §RW$FG$%ZDS$TSG$TSZ%U(); §$"§%"§$!!();
```

### To access the data:

```
<?php
$file = fopen(__FILE__, 'rb');
// Go to the end of the __halt_compiler();
fseek($file, __COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__);
echo stream_get_contents($file);
__halt_compiler(); §RW$FG$%ZDS$TSG$TSZ%U(); §$"§%"§$!!();
```

This will output `§RW$FG$%ZDS$TSG$TSZ%U(); §$"§%"§$!!();`

Comment: So `__halt_compliler(); ` can only be at the end of file?

Comment: Not it can be anywhere in the file. I'll edit in another example

Comment: I'm curious how to resume compile?

Comment: In that php file, you can't. You need to start a new php process.

Comment: And how can one make use of `§RW$FG$%ZDS$TSG$TSZ%U(); §$"§%"§$!!();`?

Comment: Edited in an example of data access

Comment: nice I didn't even know this function existed :)

Comment: You could use this to attach data to other files. Use some PHP code to load the file and echo out the file data, then call `__halt_compiler()` and the rest of the file will look like it's part of that file.  Think kind of like an email signature, it would always be appended, while the first part of the PHP file is used to load dynamic data.

Comment: To anyone thinking "but you could just call exit/die()": this function gets checked even before the syntax, so even parse errors after that "function" call will be ignored.

Comment: A common use for this is to append a zip archive containing the needed files after you program's code.

Comment: psst... (It's good for malware....)

Answer (score 9):

Previously, The [ClassGenerator in the PhpSpec](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/commit/ed0bfca64e4edd9188b992550ad30b6e425ab061#diff-43976ba065e7c336f26bf7a1db9ddadbL102) unit testing library provided a good example of using  `__halt_compiler()`, which the [PHP class contains a code template for a PHP class](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/aa631acd95c920ad20c1ab52bbbc82c8299b8dce/687474703a2f2f692e737461636b2e696d6775722e636f6d2f4a61724a302e6a7067).

They've recently update to read the template from a seperate file, but initially the `getTemplate()` method will attempt to read the PHP code template provided in the file that follows the `__halt_compiler()` call. This avoids the `<?php` token from getting parsed.

```
/**
 * The Class Generator is responsible for generating the classes from a resource
 * in the appropriate folder using the template provided
 */
class ClassGenerator
{
    //...

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getTemplate()
    {
        return file_get_contents(__FILE__, null, null, __COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__);
    }
}
__halt_compiler();<?php%namespace_block%

class %name%
{
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another possible use.  I have a long file of PHP functions.  Many of these aren't currently valid, but might be required soon.  I want to disable them, but not entirely delete them.  I want the code to remain visible to all developers so that they can reinstate the code if they need it.  Also anyone searching via grep would still find the code.

So I move the code to the end of the file, and want to "comment it out".  However the functions themselves have comments in.  So I would need to start a new block comment after the end of each block comment in the original code.  __halt_compiler(); does the job without changing any other lines.

(If I delete the code and commit that to a version control system, that does allow me to reinstate the code, but it wouldn't be visible to other developers unless they new to look.)

Comment: "but not entirely delete them in case I change my mind" --- that's why you use source control version. You never comment out the code - you delete them and revert when necessary. So, a terrible example caused by terrible development practices.

Comment: OK, I'll admit I had simplified my answer (now clarified) because I felt the question was primarily about  __halt_compiler rather than best development practices.  Potentially your assertions "every file must be in source control", and "it's never right to comment out code" are a little restrictive.  Even if you wouldn't do it, others like me might do it in specific situations.  Please let's not start a flame war - I feel I have explained a valid use case.