# How to stop PHP code execution?

Tags: php

Is there a way to **immediately** stop PHP code execution?

I am aware of [exit](http://php.net/exit) but it clearly states:

> Terminates execution of the script. Shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed even if exit is called.

So what I want to achieve is to stop the PHP code execution **exactly** when I call *exit* or whatever.

Any help?

Edit: After Jenson's answer

Trial 1:

```
function newExit() {
    __halt_compiler();
}    
echo "start";
newExit();    
echo "you should not see this";
```

Shows `Fatal error: __HALT_COMPILER() can only be used from the outermost scope in` which was pretty expected.

Trial 2:

```
function newExit() {
    include 'e.php';
}
echo "start";
newExit();
echo "you should not see this";
```

e.php just contains `__halt_compiler();`

This shows **startyou should not see this**

**Edit: Why I want to do this?**

I am working on an application that includes a proprietary library (required through virtual host config file to which I don't have access) that comes as encrypted code. Is a sort of monitoring library for security purpose. One of it's behaviours is that it registers some shutdown functions that log the instance status (it saves stats to a database)

What I want to do is to **disable** this logging for some specific conditions based on (remote IP)

Comment: die(); may be it help

Comment: @ArthurYakovlev there's almost no difference in the behaviour between exit and die

Comment: >This language construct is equivalent to exit().

Comment: According to the documentation die() is equivalent to exit()

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? Usually people who wrote classes or shutdown functions wrote them for a reason.

Comment: This is an extreme and unusual behaviour to want. @skafandri hasn't provided an extreme and unusual use case to need to do this. What is the need? In your examples, `exit()` would work fine.

Comment: @digital-chris check my update with the use case

Comment: @skafandri, but again it would be useful to know exactly what you are trying to do. Why would you want to exit in a messy way when you can do it in a clean way with `exit()`?

Comment: @return-this-lau as stated in my edit, I want to disable the logging for some specific conditions, like you would disable authentication for a trusted IP for example...

Answer (score 20):

**Please see the following information from user Pekka 웃**

According to the manual, destructors are executed even if the script gets terminated using `die()` or `exit()`:

> The destructor will be called even if script execution is stopped using `exit()`. Calling exit() in a destructor will prevent the remaining shutdown routines from executing.

According to this [PHP: destructor vs register_shutdown_function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236795/php-destructor-vs-register-shutdown-function), the destructor does **not** get executed when PHP's execution time limit is reached (Confirmed on Apache 2, PHP 5.2 on Windows 7).

The destructor also does **not** get executed when the script terminates because the memory limit was reached. (Just tested)

The destructor **does** get executed on fatal errors (Just tested) Update: The OP can't confirm this - there seem to be fatal errors where things are different

It does **not** get executed on parse errors (because the whole script won't be interpreted)

The destructor will certainly not be executed if the server process crashes or some other exception out of PHP's control occurs.

**Referenced in this question**
[Are there any instances when the destructor in PHP is NOT called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434270/are-there-any-instances-when-the-destructor-in-php-is-not-called)

Answer (score 8):

whats wrong with `return` ?

```
echo "you will see this";
return;    
echo "you will not see this";
```

Comment: What, if you want to break execution of PHP script not in the main flow, but in some function or method? Using `return` will exit current method and **won't** stop code execution.

Comment: since return can interrupt execution the answer still valid in the context you use

Comment: The execution must _stop_. `return` will... _return_ execution to the higher context (i.e. function, thread or flow that has executed given function). `return` by no mean stop the execution of the entire script. I still don't get how do you want to use `return` to halt the execution of the entire script. Your answer will work in function-less scenario only.

Answer (score 4):

You could try to kill the PHP process:

```
exec('kill -9 ' . getmypid());
```

Comment: Highly dependand of the execution method (cgi, fcgi, webserver module ...) and permissions though.

Comment: It seems to be the best way to avoid request from being logged in access_log.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `__halt_compiler` function which will Halt the compiler execution

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.halt-compiler.php

Comment: The compiler won't execute the code after '__halt_compiler' but is it really not going to call the destructors and shutdown functions? I didn't check actually but I guess it would call them (can't think of any reason why it wouldn't).

Comment: Does the compiler still see class/function definitions after that statement? There are differences between compile time and run time in PHP that may be an issue here.

Comment: Also note the following, err, note from the docs: `__halt_compiler() can only be used from the outermost scope.`

Comment: @ToBe According to comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270486/whats-halt-compiler-in-php-for `Because PHP would already be running by the time exit is called; __halt_compiler tells PHP to ignore everything after it as if it were inside one big /* comment */` It seems to not see anything

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the obvious `die()` and `exit()`, this also works:

```
<?php
echo "start";
__halt_compiler();
echo "you should not see this";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you understand what "exit" states

```
Terminates execution of the script. Shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed even if exit is called.
```

It's normal to do that, it must clear it's memmory of all the variables and functions you called before. Not doing this would mean your memmory would remain stuck and ocuppied in your RAM, and if this would happen several times you would need to reboot and flush your RAM in order to have any left.

Answer (score 0):

or try

```
trigger_error('Die', E_ERROR);
```

Comment: Should be equivalent of exit() or die() but is also dependant on used error handler.