# An expresstion in if statement should return TRUE or FALSE, but it runs a function. PHP

Tags: php

A newbie question.
Here is a function and an if statement.

```
<?php

    function test(){
        echo "somedata";    
    }

    if(test())      

?>
```

This code produces:
somedata

According to documentation an if expression should only return TRUE or FALSE, but apart of it, function runs. Why it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP evaluates the `if` expression in order to know if the epression yields a truthy value or not. There is no other way to find out than to execute the functions that appear in the expression.

In this example it is very clear:

```
 if (sqrt(4) > 1)
```

PHP must of course call the function `sqrt`, except that in this case it is a function without side-effects, while your function `test` also performs an `echo`. Secondly, it returns a value, while `test` doesn't. But that PHP can only find out by executing the function.

Note that the expression can in general return anything, but PHP has rules to what [it considers *truthy* or *falsy*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting):

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered `FALSE`:
>
> - the boolean `FALSE` itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type `NULL` (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
>
> Every other value is considered `TRUE` (including any resource).

In case a function runs without executing a `return` statement, the returned value is `null`, so the `if` condition will be falsy according to the above rules.

Comment: It's worth noting that `echo "somedata"` is completely irrelevant here. The function can have empty body as well - as long as it got no `return` it completely does not matter what the function does.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, except of course if the function performs an `exit()` (or the equivalent `die()`), or throws an exception. There some [other creative ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457734/how-to-stop-php-code-execution) to break the normal execution flow.

Comment: In such case `if()` wont be evaluated so I'd say it still does not matter as we assume normal flow. Turning machine off or killing PHP process may also affect this `if()` when timed accurately, but this is not we shall bother.