# Force stop a php page from loading

Tags: php, html

I am working HTML and PHP for the first time. I have a php page that has a submit button which calls a shell script. This shell script performs some tasks which takes about 10-15 mins.
When the submit button is clicked, a new page opens which prints some info immediately and then runs that script in the background.

However the browser tab shows the page to still be loading. Is there anyway I can stop the loading bar. The php code snippet looks something like this:

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'Test') {
    $result = liveExecuteCommand("/usr/bin/test.sh &");
}
```

Comment: cal the script once the page is loaded not immediately or you can use die() function to stop that page

Comment: Didnt get you? Can you elaborate?

Comment: What is `liveExecuteCommand` supposed to do?

Comment: $proc = popen("$cmd 2>&1 ;", 'r');
 
      $live_output     = "";
      $complete_output = "";
 
      while (!feof($proc))
     {
         $live_output     = fread($proc, 4096);
         $complete_output = $complete_output . $live_output;
         echo "$live_output";
         @ flush();
     }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continue PHP execution after sending HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833013/continue-php-execution-after-sending-http-response)

Comment: You will find this answer interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469376/3897122

Answer (score 1):

Use the exec command and redirect the output to null:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'Test') {
    exec("/usr/bin/test.sh > /dev/null &");
}
```

This should not wait for the process to finish.

Comment: Do I need to include something to be able to use the exec command? It seems to be throwing some error if I directly use it

Comment: @VedangGutgutia no - execute is and build in function. If you run it on some shared hosts, it might be blocked (but in this case, others shouldn't also work)

Comment: @Philipp it doesnt seem to be working for me. Any other way I can go about this?

Comment: If SELinux is working on your machine you should put it into permissive mode. Or find a way to let php execute commands with SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

Destructors are executed even if the script gets terminated using `die()` or `exit()`.

**For More Details :**
*[exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)*
*[how to stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457734/how-to-stop-php-code-execution)*

Comment: It seems, the interpreter stucks in `liveExecuteCommand`. Putting an exit before it, wouldn't execute the script at all and putting it after wouldn't make it better

Comment: Yep supposed ;)